# How to add a default constraint on orderID

Tags: sql, reporting-services, constraints, default

```
SELECT 
    O.*,
    C.CustName,
    OD.[PartNo], OD.[PartDesc], 
    OD.[Quantity], OD.[Price], OD.[Total],
    OD.[Price] * O.[ExchangeRateToGBP] AS PriceGBP,
    OD.[Total] * O.[ExchangeRateToGBP] AS TotalGBP
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblOrder] O
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[tblOrderDetails] OD ON O.OrderNo = OD.OrderNo
INNER JOIN  
    [dbo].[tblCustomer] C ON O.CustNo = C.CustNo
WHERE 
    (OrderId = @OrderId )
```

Can anybody tell me what to do in order for me to get a default value for the order Id? Currently the user must enter an `OrderId` to view the parts that they want (which is what I want as well). However, if they do not have a `OrderId` then how can I get it so that they just receive all the orders?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to give the variable a default value which will be used when no value is supplied:

```
DECLARE @OrderId VARCHAR(20) = NULL;
```

and then change your WHERE criteria:

```
WHERE (@OrderId IS NULL OR OrderId = @OrderId)
```

Comment: This is still giving me no option other than entering an orderID.  `Please enter a value for the parement 'Order Id'. The parameter cannot be blank.`

Comment: What are you using for your reporting tool?  Sounds like you need to change something in the report in order to allow for a blank parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 ...
 WHERE OrderId = @OrderId OR @OrderId IS NULL
```

When user does not provide `@OrderId` value second part will return true and retrieve all records.

Comment: This is also still giving me no option other than entering an orderID. ** Please enter a value for the parement 'Order Id'. The parameter cannot be blank.**